# Difference between JS encode and URL encode

Tags: javascript, web, encoding, xss, urlencode

What is the difference between JavaScript encoding and URL encoding. I am not able to figure out exact difference between them. Also that are following types of encoding are called

1. `%HH`
2. `\u00HH`
3. `&#HH;`
4. `\\`
5. `\HH`

Any more encoding schemes used in Web technologies?

Comment: Where did you get the term, "JavaScript encoding"? Do you mean JSON?

Comment: @pointy I gave an interview and interviewer was continuously stressing on JavaScript encoding. I thought I do not know about it.

Comment: @Bergi not completely.

Comment: @Pointy It is another term for JavaScript escaping. Not JSON itself, but a subset (by that I mean used per string literal). e.g. changing `"` to `\x22`

Answer (score 1):

> `%HH`

[Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as used in URIs.

> `\u00HH`

Unicode [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). For JavaScript specific things, read [the spec on *String literals*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4).

> `&#HH;`

[HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference), or [numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references).

> `\\`

Could be anything. Usually escaping the backslash when the backslash is used for escaping things.

> `\HH`

Maybe you're referring to a named escape sequence here. See [escape sequences in C-based languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Comment: If I escape all the data using &#HH; or %HH encoding, will I be completely safeguarded for XSS attack?

Comment: @Gaurav: No. URI encoding should not play a role in XSS. Escaping strings in the HTML is definitely good practice, but there are still XSS attacks that can work around that.

Comment: `<img src="#" onmouseover="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['xss']); ?>">` is vulnerable to `alert(1)` string. What encoding is suggested? There are more such cases.

Comment: `onmouseover` does expect a js expression, so I'm not sure what you want. You might consider something like `<img src="#" onmouseover="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("alert(".json_encode($_GET['xss']).");"); ?>">`

Comment: Does `json_encode` only gives wrapper on double quotation? Also is it available in all web development languages?

Comment: No, `json_encode` does escape the whole string in a js-compatible manner. Yes, [JSON](http://json.org/) is available for nearly every language.

Comment: @Gaurav: To answer your question `What encoding is suggested`, the answer is none. Do not put untrusted data inside `onmouseover` as it will be executed. Check out the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).